# What are requirements on "Facebook Login integration" for successful submission to App Center?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-app-center

I'm struggling to submit an Android/iOS application to App Center, however I'm getting constantly rejected with the following reason:

> **General Feedback:**
>
> - Your Android app does not appear to have Facebook Login integration. Please either implement Facebook Login or remove this  integration as a listed platform in the developer app. See more  details here
> - Your iOS app does not appear to have Facebook Login integration. Please either implement Facebook Login or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app. See more details here

Facebook login button is placed in Settings dialog, where a normal email/password login is located as well.

Unfortunately the review team doesn't specify why exactly it appears to them that Facebook Login integration is missing.

So, are there any specific requirements on Login implementation which I may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the one thing that helped passing review was adding Facebook logo on the login button in the Settings screen.

Answer (score 0):

Review the [Facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) - They outline instructions on how to get started with Facebook integration into an Android app [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/), talk about Facebook authentication [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/), and have a tutorial for a Facebook login [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/). Perhaps your issue is not following the outlined requirements, so you have a login, but not in the proper format.

Comment: I have read and followed all these instructions with the only difference:
As I use `PreferenceActivity` for application settings including user authentication, I have implemented a custom `Preference` with all `LoginButton` functionality (handling `Session`, etc) instead of putting `LoginButton` there, which would look really out-of-place.

So, the question is, do I need to mess with existing application layout and place a large Facebook LoginButton on the very first screen even if users don't even need to login to start using the app?

Comment: I believe you do need to change the layout (maybe on the opening screen you can have your secondary login option as well?) - however, I am not sure so I +1'd your question in hopes of it getting more traction

Comment: I don't know the statistics are on this but it may be easier just to do FB login alone as so many use it, however I am not sure what your implementation is so maybe your secondary login is necessary

Comment: At least, there is already a pretty large userbase registered without Facebook Login

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Login Button. Instead, have a made function in appdelegate to get the FBSession.

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI andCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void)) action{
BOOL theResult = [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                   FBSessionState state,
                                                                   NSError *error) {
                                                   if (state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                                                       action();
                                                   }
                                                   //action();
                                                   [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                       state:state
                                                                       error:error];
                                               }];
return theResult;
}
```

Then When I want to post, I do this:

```
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [theAppDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES andCompletionBlock:^{
    //Your Code            
        [self postToWall];

    }];
}
else {
        [self postToWall];
 }

- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {
// we defer request for permission to post to the moment of post, then we check for the permission
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
    [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                               defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                 if (!error) {
                                                     action();
                                                 }
                                             }];
      } else {
          action();
     }
}

   -(void)postToWall {
[self performPublishAction:^{
    NSMutableDictionary* params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    kFacebookAppID, @"api_key",
                                    kLink,          @"link",
                                    photo,          @"picture",
                                    kAppName,       @"name",
                                    kDescription,   @"description",
                                    nil];

    FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    FBRequest *theRequest = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] graphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params1 HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [connection addRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Result from Facebook request: %@",result);
        if (!error) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UploadComplete" object:nil];
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }];
    [connection start];

}]; 
}
```

Add these functions as well.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
// attempt to extract a token from the url
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}

/*
 * Callback for session changes.
 */
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        if (!error) {
            // We have a valid session
            NSLog(@"User session found");
        }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
 object:session];

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does it pass Facebook review?

Comment: This app where it was implemented has not gone to the appstore, like to point out here that when I am posting to facebook it is by users choice to press the Post to facebook button.

Comment: My app isn't posting anything to Facebook, it just uses Facebook Login instead of manually entering e-mail and password

Comment: Are you getting any error? Because bundle identifier has to match in FB and your app when you have FB login from settings.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Everything works fine and users successfully login via Facebook both in iOS and Android versions. The problem appears when I try to submit the app to be published in Facebook App Center. The app just fails Facebook's review with obscure message cited in my original question and no further explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Facebook has its own developer guidelines that you can find here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/guidelines/ . Almost at the end of the document you have a section calle "Common submission mistakes". Check it, follow the links and perhaps there you can find where your problem is.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The only phrase related to my problem there is:
"Mobile apps built for iOS and Android must use Facebook Login."

The question still remains: what are requirements on "using Facebook Login"?